# Option to preserve empty arrays and objects at "qs.stringify()" funtion of qs package in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, stringify, qs

I want to also preserve an empty array but the qs package is deleting the empty array key from the stringified data:

```js
const data = {
  key: [],
  name: "Lower"
};

const stringifiedData = qs.stringify(data);
console.log(stringifiedData);`
```

The result should be like this:

```
key=[]&name=Lower
```

Comment: What you're after is the query string if you had `key: "[]"` in your object. So even if you were able to have your object stringify to include `key=[]` in your query string, you're going to get an object with `key: "[]"` when it's parsed back (unless you employ some custom logic on the parsing side, but at that point, it's probably easier to check if `key` exists, and if it doesn't, set it to an empty object after parsing it).

Comment: I want to get key like this key=[] after parsing with qs.stringify()

Comment: Can you clarify why you want this? `key` has no data so there is nothing to serialize.

Comment: Actually on requested url they are accepting like this to clear the data with respect to key